# Transactional data over multiple years (Customer ID, Date, Price)

Tags: data-request, business, companies, time-series

To build models to predict customer behavior, I am searching for transactional data over multiple years (i.e. > 3 years). My focus is to assess the quality of long-term predictions, thus the longer the time period the better.

Minimum requirement in terms of variables would be:

1. Customer ID
2. Purchase/order/transaction date
3. Price of goods/services sold

In a perfect world, these datasets would be released under a GPL license and also include information like:

- Date of first purchase ever (which facilitates cohort analysis)
- Socio-demographic information on the individual customer
- Product ID, as well as further details of the products bought such as product category

Examples are manifold and include order/transaction/purchase histories from an online store, a car/bike share network, transactions from a gas station network, ...

I do know about the Superstore dataset that ships with Tableau and has 4 years of transactional data (http://community.tableausoftware.com/docs/DOC-1236). However, this is simulated data and does not show the patterns one usually observes in real world transactional data.

Comment: Any luck finding any good transactional data like this?  Amazing how hard it is to find..

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

Kaggle once conducted a competition with 22GB of real transaction data:

- http://www.kaggle.com/c/acquire-valued-shoppers-challenge/data (registration required)

But look after the terms of use (only for the purposes of competition) and so on.

Comment: I am aware of this dataset, but it is only covers transactions for 1 year. I am search specifically for a dataset > 3 years.

Comment: By the way, there are many "short" transactional datasets available, see e.g. http://www.marketingedge.org/marketing-programs/data-set-library.

Answer (score 1):

Sites that aren't "stores" are more likely to share customer data. So take a look at the crowdfunding sites:

- [Crowdtilt API](https://www.tilt.com/learn/developers) and [git](https://github.com/Crowdtilt/crowdtilt-api-spec/)
- Indiegogo ([scraping example](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-API-for-Indiegogo))
- Kickstarter ([unofficial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582470/2327328) and [more](https://github.com/markolson/kickscraper/issues/16#issuecomment-31409151))

You can get a set of contributors by looping over campaigns.

---

If you are more ambitious, you could do the same for an online store. You'll have to do some research to see if any fits your needs. I think with a combined API and scraping approach, you can build a decent dataset of customer transactions.

- etsy.com has an [API](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/api_basics) which includes [Feedback](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/seller_tools#section_feedback)

> Each transaction can have up to two feedback records, one left by the buyer for the seller, and one left by the seller for the buyer. Feedback is optional; so not all transaction will have feedback records (although most will.)

- [ebay API](https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/what-ebay-api)

---

Regarding the demographics, I doubt any site will include demographic information - but consider [predicting age and gender from name](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-to-tell-someones-age-when-all-you-know-is-her-name/)).

Comment: Can you really scrape the individual amount that any person has pleged to a Kickstarter/Indiegogo campaign? I already did scrape Kickstarter quite some time ago and at that time this information was not accessible.