# How do you get auction data on the same individuals across auctions?

Tags: data-request, api

Is there any way to get data on auctions (preferably eBay) for the same persons across multiple auctions? Is there any API access possible? Any open data sets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transactional data over multiple years (Customer ID, Date, Price)](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/transactional-data-over-multiple-years-customer-id-date-price)

Comment: philshem just to clarify, I am not sure how this relates to my question at all, I am sorry if I am misunderstood. My point is that I would need auction data .. i.e. eBay, for a research article.