# historical transactions for bidders in e-auctions

Tags: data-request

I need a dataset for my research, which contains historical transactions for bidders in e-auctions for example: profile information, number of bidding auctions, number of wins in auctions, and number of canceling bids.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transactional data over multiple years (Customer ID, Date, Price)](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/transactional-data-over-multiple-years-customer-id-date-price)

Comment: dear Patrick Hoefler,

Comment: I'm guessing that the rationale for this not being a duplicate is the reference to auctions as opposed to other kinds of data? Personally, I'm not enthusiastic about very specific data requests as questions on this site—this kind of trivial but salient detail is one reason why. But so far the community mostly seems OK with them, so I don't see why this should be closed.

Comment: This question seems to be asking for a different data hunt than the referenced question.