# Transaction dataset over multiple years

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for some transaction datasets for retailing store over multiple years (>=3 years) for my Master's degree thesis. A transaction contains:

- Customer ID
- Quality
- Price
- Product ID
- Order Date and Time

I have searched lots of datasets, but they are not suitable for my research. Does anyone have ideas about where can I find the dataset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Quality*? Do you mean *Quantity*? And in that case, is the *Price* for one unit?

Comment: Is this a repeat question for http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/transactional-data-over-multiple-years-customer-id-date-price, under a different alias? Don't do that. The content and edit timestamps are suspiciously similar.

Comment: Seems like a blunt copy of my previous question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/transactional-data-over-multiple-years-customer-id-date-price