# Contractual data over multiple years

Tags: data-request, longitudinal

To build models to predict customer behavior, I am searching for **individual-level contractual data over multiple years** (i.e. > 3 years). My focus is to assess the quality of long-term predictions, thus the longer the time period the better. (See [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/transactional-data-over-multiple-years-customer-id-date-price) for a similar question on transactional data.)

Minimum requirement in terms of variables would be:

1. Customer ID
2. Start Date Contract
3. End Date Contract
4. Contractual Fees
5. (If firm sells multiple types of contracts: Contract Type)

In a perfect world, these datasets would be released under a GPL like license and also include information like:

- Date of first contract ever (which facilitates cohort analysis)
- Socio-demographic information on the individual customer

Examples are manifold and include data from insurances, SAAS firms, VOD subscription services, ...

Comment: B2G contracts: https://github.com/antontarasenko/gpq

Comment: That's unfortunately from the perspective of a single buyer/contractee, I am looking for data from the perspective of the vendor.

Comment: These are 200+ agencies making purchases independently.

Comment: This data provides a good overview in a specific area. Unfortunately, this doesn't allow to analyze customer behavior in any traditional way. Thus, we need one firm that offers one or multiple services/products/contracts and its customers.