# Data set for Social Commerce

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, social-media

I am looking for a reviews/rating dataset for my social commerce application (for building up the recommendation engine). **In this dataset, along with product info and reviews/ratings by users, I also require user demographics information like age, gender, occupation.**

I have looked through [Amazon datasets](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/), unfortunately, they don't have the user info.

I have also looked through [UCI repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/), but couldn't find anything relevant.

I came upon this [paper](http://www2013.wwwconference.org/proceedings/p1521.pdf), and found the dataset description exactly the way I wanted, but unfortunately, this  dataset is not open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transactional data over multiple years (Customer ID, Date, Price)](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/transactional-data-over-multiple-years-customer-id-date-price)